# Outlook 2010 Event Creation Date

Tags: windows-7-backup

I am using Outlook 2010 and want to know how to view the creation date of an Outlook event entered at the top of a specific date in the calendar.  I see the last modified date in the lower right-hand corner when I open the event but need to know the original creation date and how to locate that date.

Answer (score 0):

- [Enable the Developer tab](http://www.addintools.com/documents/word/where-develop-tab.html), if it's not already.
- Open the appointment you want to find the creation date of.
- Click the *Developer* tab, and select "**Design This Form**".
- Click the *(All Fields)* tab.
- In the *Select from* drop-down, select **Date/Time fields**.
- "*Created*" will be one of those fields, and it should contain the creation time-stamp you're looking for.